# How to justify a paragraph block when creating a new post in wordpress in version 5.2.1 (May 2019)

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a new post in my Wordpress site (version 5.2.1) and I don't see a justify icon anymore. And it seems that many items have been removed too in this new version. Looks great though.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to justify a single post, you can use

```
text-align:justify
```

Or else if you want to customize multiple posts, visit
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently